# delete list element by index while iterating using python

Tags: python, list

In a list, I have duplicate elements that I want to remove.

The following code doesn't work:

Note: 
temp containts the list of indexes of elements that I want to remove.

x is my list.

```
temp = self.list_duplicates(x)
for index in tmp:
   del x[index]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you just want to keep unique items in a list, you can use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: This is true, but sets don't have order, which can make them not work for some problems.

Comment: Also see [Removing items from a list while iterating over the list](http://sopython.com/canon/95/removing-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-the-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a new list with a comprehension:

```
x = [element for (i,element) in enumerate(x) if i not in temp]
```

If you want to remove only duplicates, i.e. leaving one copy of the original, there is a better way to do that:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
x = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

`x.pop(index)` will remove the item at index. However, `x = [x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if x[i] not in x[:i]]` will remove the duplicates more quickly.

Comment: `for i in len(x)` will raise `TypeError`.  And `x.pop(index)` will offset the other indices, so careful with that.

Comment: Good catch on the first, fixed. The second is true, but that will be true any time you remove an element from the middle of a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list with the following:

**Edit**: Works now for list of indices

```
x = list(filter(lambda item: x.index(item) not in temp, x))
```

Comment: `temp` is a list of indices, not items.

Comment: Have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

No one addressed the first part of the question. So, for removing duplicate items its wise to use `set()`, it removes the duplicate items and returns a arbitrary list of unique items.

```
lst = [1,1,2,3,4,4]
new_lst = list(set(lst))
print(lst)
```

It will return unique list of elements in an arbitrary manner Eg : [1,4,2,3]